# Prove that a sentence is tautology, satisfiable but not tautology or unsatisfiable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

I am trying to understand how to determine whether a sentence is a tautology, satisfiable but not tautology or unsatisfiable using the right approach

Example: (¬up → ¬down) → ¬up

---

**I tried the following**

(¬up → ¬down) → ¬up  = (up ⋁ ¬down) → ¬up

then I get stucked in the next step

Comment: Let $ q= $ up and $p= $ down and write out the truth tables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to check whether a formula is satisfiable, tautological or contradictory is to have a look at the truth table:

- the last column has at least one row with *true*: the formula is satisfiable
- the last column has only rows with *true*'s: the formula is tautological
- the last column has only rows with *false*'s: the formula is contradictory/unsatisfiable

So let's have a look at the truth table for the formula $(\neg u \to \neg d) \to \neg u$ ("u" abbreviates "up", "d" abbreviates "down"):

```
u d | ¬u ¬d ¬u→¬d (¬u→¬d)→¬u
t t | f  f    t        f    
t f | f  t    t        f    
f t | t  f    f        t    
f f | t  t    t        t
```

Since the last column has at least one row with *true*, the formula is satisfiable/non-contradictory.
Since the last row has alwo rows with *false*, the formlua is not tautological.
A formula which is satisfiable but not tautological, i.e. which has both *true*'s and *false*'s in its truth table, is also called **contingent**.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

In reference to your example:

$(P \Rightarrow Q)$ $\Rightarrow P$ is clearly satisifiable when $P$ and $Q$ are true,
but it is not a tautology. Consider the implication $P \Rightarrow Q$ which is true when $P$ is false and $Q$ is true. Now consider the sentence $(P \Rightarrow Q)\Rightarrow P$. We will end up with $T \Rightarrow F$ since $P$ is false and so the sentence is not a tautology.

Answer (score 0):

Possible methods to determine the semantic status of a formula ( tautology? antilogy? contingent formula?)

(1) **Transform the formula using logical equivalences.**

- If the formula is equivalent to a known tautology, then the formula is a tautology.
- If the formula is equivalent to a known antilogy ( logical falsehood) then it is a logical falsehood.
- If the negation of your formula is equivalent to a known tautology, then the formula is an antilogy.
- If the negation of the formula is equivalent to a known antilogy, then the formula is a tautology.

(2) **If none of the above methods works, use a truth table.**

Remark. The fact that method (1) does not work proves nothing ( it does not prove that it is not a tautology or an antilogy). Or I should say, it only proves that **I** did not manage to find an equivalent tautology/ antilogy. Some more clever logician might manage to find what I did not manage to find.

However, method 1's failure makes it **probable** ( simply probable) that the formula is **contingent**.

Anyway, a truth table will tell you what is the logical status of the formula.

(3) Since there is a correspondance between semantics and syntax, you can also try to derive ( as conclusion )the consequent of the conditional from the antecedent taken as hypothesis . **If you manage to do that, the soundness of your formal system ( for example, the natural deduction system)  guarantees you that the formula  : "antecedent --> consequent"  is a tautology.**